CSV file is treating commas in string values as delimiters and shifting data into wrong columns. Is there a way to fix this in R?
I have a large csv file that I pulled from an online database that doesn't seem to read well. It looks like it treats commas in a couple of the columns as delimiters and then parses the data into new columns.
The site is very old and buggy and hasn't been updated in a while. It only lets me export the data as a CSV and I can't even scrub the data from the HTML code because it glitches when I switch pages. So basically I'm stuck with what I have.

Is there a way to fix this when importing into R or within R?

CSV FILE SPECS:
Rows: 26009 Columns: 11
── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
chr (10): Status, Customer, Location, City, Description, PO, Date, Total, Accepted, Rejected
dbl  (1): Number
I have 11 columns but have a few rows where data has been shifted into a 12th, 13th and even 14th columm.
Here's a sample of the data:

This is how the data should look:

The most problematic columns seem to primarily be Customer and Location (mostly Location). The last two columns (Accepted, Rejected) are not particularly important because that information is already in the 'Status' column.
I'm still just brainstorming but I have a unique list of cities that I have pulled so I thought about using the 'City' column as a reference for how far to shift the data - at least as a first pass. For example, in row 9 the city 'Ray City' is in the 'PO' column, therefore all of the cells before that should be concatenated with the string in the 'Location' column along with the commas ex. "LDS - Ray City 1, 4, 10"
This method is likely going to require a lot of corrections so if anyone has a better idea I'm all ears
EDIT----------------------

Number, Status, Customer, Location, City, Description, PO, Date, Total, Accepted, Rejected
56529,Open,BGIS Canada LP re. Bank of Montreal,BMO Yorktown,Yorktown,Curb Repair,,6/13/2024,322,,,
56528,Accepted,First Bank,Deer Valley,Sechelt,Asphalt Concerns,,6/13/2024,14245,True,,
56527,Open,Loblaws Inc.,RCSS West,Taliha,Tree and Shrub Removal,,6/13/2024,1200,,,
56526,Open,Strata ads232,2210 fakeStreet Drive,Winnipeg,Laneway Wash Out Rehabilitation,,6/13/2024,1000,,,
56525,Open,Loblaws Inc.,RCSS West,Taliha,Irrigation Repairs,,6/13/2024,8999,,,
56524,Accepted,BGIS C/O TD Canada ,TD Bank - Sandy,Sandy,Pot Hole Repairs,,6/13/2024,1335,True,,
56452,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Wansuka, Wildwood,Edmonton,Parking Lot Improvements,,6/5/2024,54321,,,
56427,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Ray City 1, 4, 10,Ray City,Line Painting,,6/3/2024,1234.56,,,
56426,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Ray City 2, 3,Ray City,Line Painting,,6/3/2024,453,,,
56425,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Ray City 5, 6, 8 Cobblestone,Ray City,Line Painting,,6/3/2024,789.1,,,
56424,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Ray City 7, 9, PR,Ray City,Line Painting,,6/3/2024,4567.89,,,
56203,Open,Monty Developments,Broadview Building A, B and C,Port Francis,2024 - 25 Winter Snow and Ice Management,,5/21/2024,33270,,,
56076,Open,JLLRES,LDS - Starburn Bay, Criston, Legacy, McKena,Halifax,2024 Lot Sweep,,5/14/2024,2845.13,,,
55460,Accepted,JLLRES,LDS - Kelvin 1, 2, 3 YSA,Kelvin,Refinish Gym Floor,,3/25/2024,8910.12,True,,
55007,Rejected,RPD,ERBC Office - MHSD, SBC, ISBS, MLA,Port Francis,Litter Pick,,2/21/2024,655.34,False,True,


So you are having issues getting data  from CSV to Excel, and it's not about reading Excel CSV exports from R? As you get 11 columns with readr, is there still an issue? Have you tried writing the file from R with write_excel_csv() / write_excel_csv2() to check if Excel is happy with readr output? Also, how do you open it in Excel? Just open? Through Data tab / Power Query? Regarding details in your question, could you please open that file in a text editor and include first ~10 lines , as text. Or just an ouput from readr::read_lines("yourcsvfile.csv", n_max = 10) |> dput()

Assuming that's real data, I'd be upset if I was one of your customers and you shared my information like that.  But that aside, my guess is the CSV is badly formed (no quotes around fields).  If you can't control how the CSV is created (are there any options?), I'd revisit the web scraping, because there'd be no easy way to work out where things belong: if you were expecting two columns and got A.B,C, you'd have no way to automatically know if it should be "A,B" and "C" or "A" and "B,C"

We can't really tell what you have without some sample lines of the CSV but assuming that the problem is that there are no quotes around the fields containing commas then it might still be that the commas within fields are always followed by a space and the others are not so just (1) replace every comma with a character, semicolon say, that does not appear in the file, then (2) replace semicolon followed by space with a comma and space and then (3) read in the file separating the fields by semicolon.

@Hobo it's not real data. One of the locations is 2210 fakeStreet Drive lol

Find out how to save your csv file using semicolon (;) as delimiter, then read it with read.csv2() or read::read_csv2()

@margusl You're right, I just noticed it was dropping data, that's why it was showing 11 columns. I added the CSV text above

@G.Grothendieck Nice! I'll try this

@margusl Are you certain the OP's original data had the linefeed characters you added?

@RonRosenfeld linefeeds were present in OP's edit, I only added code fences to make those visible. If you have Inline or Side-by-side active in edit view, SO shows difference between rendered outputs, if you switch to Side-by-side Markdown you should see a lot less "red" - https://i.sstatic.net/Ttkmp1Jj.png

1) Read the lines of the file, remove the final comma so that the header and data lines have the same number of fields, replace commas with semicolon, replace semicolon followed by space with comma followed by space and then read in the
data (lines 2+) and separately the header (since the header has commas followed by spaces).
File <- "jgm13.csv"
DF <- File |>
  readLines() |>
  gsub(",$", "", x = _) |>
  chartr(",", ";", x = _) |>
  gsub("; ", ", ", x = _) |>
  textConnection() |>
  read.table(sep = ";", fill = TRUE, skip = 1, col.names = 
    read.table(File, nrows = 1, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE, fill = TRUE))

2) Another approach is to perform the text processing in awk.
Define an awk program in a text file, jgm13.awk, as follows:
{ if (NR == 1) gsub(/, /, ";")
  else { sub(/,$/, ""); gsub(/,/, ";"); gsub(/; /, ", ") }
  print
}

and then from R:
read.csv2(pipe("awk -f jgm13.awk jgm13.csv"))

(Use gawk in place of awk if that is what you have.  On Windows gawk is available in Rtools.)
